# Is it possible to call unification engine APIs over HTTP without SSL?

Tags: unificationengine

I want to perform some tests with the unification engine currently my system is not enabled with SSL. Is it possible to call unification engine APIs over HTTP without SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unificationengine API's are SSL protected. So it is not possible to do call Api's without SSL.

Answer (score 2):

UnificationEngine (UE) is using API's of platform providers such as Facebook, Twitter etc. - those platform's API terms require SSL connections end to end, therefore UE strictly uses SSL from the developer's app to the connector and from the connector to the official platform API's.